# Закрыть форму при открытии новой

Tags: delphi

Есть три формы

Unit1

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(Self);
  Form2.ShowModal;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form3 := TForm3.Create(Self);
  Form3.ShowModal;
end;
```

Unit3

```
procedure TForm3.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Form1.Button1Click(Sender);
  Form3 := nil;
end;
```

Когда в *Form1* нажимается кнопка *Button2*, открывается *Form3*. 
При закрытии *Form3*, открывается *Form2*.
Мне нужно, чтоб при закрытии *Form3*, не только открывалась *Form2*, но и **ЗАКРЫВАЛАСЬ** ***Form3***. 
Сейчас она не закрывается, а остается висеть, находясь за *Form2*.
Все формы должны открываться «ShowModal», метод «Show» не подходит

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хм, ну что происходит - понятно: `ShowModal` - блокирующий метод, и он просто не возвращается (не давая `Form3` возможности продолжить закрытие), пока `Form2` не закроется. А так:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TForm2.Create(nil) do
  try
    ShowModal;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TForm3.Create(nil) do
  try
    ShowModal;
  finally
    Free;
  end;

  Button1Click;
end;

procedure TForm3.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
end;
```

*Update*

Хорошо, не хотите - как хотите:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form2 := TForm2.Create(nil);
  try
    Form2.ShowModal;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Form2);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Form3 := TForm3.Create(nil);
  try
    Form3.ShowModal;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Form3);
  end;

  Button1Click;
end;
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо

Comment: Вот если бы еще после создания форм, они не равнялись *nil*, было б вообще замечательно

Comment: @Konstantin78 Так, кто - они? Глобальные переменные, которые Delphi автоматически декларирует в юните формы? Удалите эти переменные, они Вам не нужны - от них только вред. Если хотите, покажите код, где Вы их используете, и я Вам скажу, как его изменить.

Comment: "Они" - это формы, Дело в том, что у меня есть куски кода, в разных модулях программы, которые я выполняю в зависимости от наличия конкретной формы ("Form <> nil"). У меня по вашему коду форма создается, но почему-то при этом *Form = nil -> true*

Comment: @Konstantin78 См. *Update* в ответе.